# how can read message, how can I decode my recieved message?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gsm

I am try to learning a home automation system on Raspberry pi through GSM, but unfortunetally I am getting error in my python coding. 
The Problem is When I want to print my received message that time I am getting this kind of response b'b\xf1\xe2\xe2\xe2' , 
So, I cant able to decode that message and If I decode that the python giving me a error like unorderable types: int() < str(().

So , I am really confused about it , can anybody help me out in this problem, How I can match my actual message and print?

here is my code and its output.

```
`import serial
 import time
 import os

 print('Welcome to Test GSM SIM900')
 ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 19200, timeout=1) #9600 is the default    for SIM900A modem
 print('Waiting for Response')

 ser.write(('AT+CMGF=1' + '\r').encode('utf-8'))
 time.sleep(1)
 print('Connection Establish')
 ser.write(('AT+CMGDA="DEL ALL"'+'\r').encode('utf-8'))
 time.sleep(1)
 print('All messages has been Deleted')

 message = ser.read(1000) # inWaiting- get the number of bytes in the inout buffer

 print(message)

 while True:
       if message == 'LED1':
           print ("LED 1 is on")
       elif message == 'LED2':
           print ("LED 2 is on")
       elif message == 'EXIT':
           print ("shuting down")
           ser.close ()
           break
       else:
           print ("Try again")
           break

  ser.close() #close the serial port



 >>> %Run GSMTRY.py
 Welcome to Test GSM SIM900
 Waiting for Response
 Connection Establish
 All messages has been Deleted
 b'b\xf1\xe2\xe2\xe2'
 Try again
 >>>
```

`